# Has MySQL always supported shorthand validation for fields?

Tags: mysql, shorthand

I am currently writing a lot of MySQL queries and noticed that I can use shorthand validation, like so:

```
SELECT id, content, date_added FROM table WHERE date_added
```

(where date_added is a default NULL timestamp and I don't have to ask specifically if it IS NOT NULL to return all results that have a timestamp)

I just need to know if this is advised against, or if this shorthand functionality became available at a certain MySQL version, as I would like to retain backwards compatibility.
I was previously certain that this didn't work and I had to write out the whole conditional, but now I cannot confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't exactly call this "shorthand validation". I'm not sure where you're getting that from.

The `WHERE` clause is just going to check for truthiness. `NULL` is not a `TRUE` value, all other non-zero values are `TRUE`.

Even though this works for you, I would still strongly advise against it. I favor very explicit database queries. We don't need any added voodoo sorcery here...

Stick with

```sql
SELECT id, content, date_added
FROM table
WHERE date_added IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what you would call it, I just see it as shorthand, and that I wanted to validate the given field, my bad

Answer (score 1):

I actually understand what you mean by your terms shorthand validation, thanks for pointing this out... I have used "WHERE 1" quite a bit to start off a "WHERE clause variable" in PHP, inspired by phpMyAdmin's queries which has been using that for quite a while, so maybe that answers your question at least somewhat...

This is from 2004:
http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/phpmyadmin-where-1t-112118.html

Comment: Just found out that this kind of thing works too: `SELECT * FROM MAIL_SUBSCRIBER WHERE !UNSUBSCRIBED` ... I mean it makes sense, just never bothered with it before...

Comment: (where UNSUBSCRIBED in this case is either 0 or 1, so it applies even outside of NULL/NOT NULL)